# How do Sine functions work in Java?

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

Really need help with understanding some math functions involving radians.

Say:

```
double SinA = (Math.sin(B) * a) / b;
```

Does `B` have to be in Radians? After executing, will `SinA` be in Radians?

Further down my example:

```
double Ainv = Math.asin(SinA);
```

Does the `Math.asin()` function only accept Radians? Will `Ainv` be in radians after executing?

Last:

```
double ADeg = Math.toDegrees(Ainv);
```

Does `Math.toDegrees()` function accept radians?

Comment: Have you, I don't know, considered _looking at documentation_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) yes, `Math.sin()` acccepts angle in radians

2) result of `sin` function can not be in radians in mathematical sence. It is just real number

3) argument of `Math.asin` is real number, which is `sin` result of some angle. But it **returns** value in radians.

4) Yes, `toDegrees` accepts radians and returns degrees.

Answer (score 2):

> Does B have to be in Radians?

Yes. `Math.sin` works for an input measured in radians.

> After executing, will SinA be in Radians?

This question doesn't really make sense. While the input for `Math.sin` should be measured in radians, the return value is dimensionless (has no units).

> Does the Math.asin() function only accept Radians?

No, it accepts any real number. If the input is between `-1.0` and `1.0` the *return value* will be measured in radians.

> Does Math.toDegrees() function accept radians?

Yes. It accepts an angle in radians, and returns an angle measured in degrees.

Answer (score 1):

All the trigonometric functions in Java operate in radians. Think of a radian as being a natural unit for an *angle*. At school we were taught to think in terms of degrees, or *gradians* (of which there are 400 in a circle) if you're French!

Since there are 360 degrees, or 2 * PI radians in a circle, to convert a degree amount to a radians one, multiply the degree amount by PI and divide by 180. `Math.toDegrees(Ainv);` performs the inverse of this.

In your case `SinA` is not an angle but the *result* of the computation, so it's in neither degrees nor radians.

Comment: But how do I convert it back from Radians to degrees? Do I use the `Math.toDegrees()` function or is there a mathematical way?

Comment: Java is nice enough to give you the function `.toDegrees()`. Or you could multiply by 180 then divide by PI. But you ought to stick to the library functions.